# how to set background for specific cells of DataGrid wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataTable and I want change background of specific cells that Their 'place' field is true.

I set ItemSource of DataGrid in C# code.

I try this code but not work :

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dg">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Place}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

In C# code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Place", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add( "23:00", "true");
            dt.Rows.Add( "21:00", "true");
            dt.Rows.Add( "19:00", "false");
            dg.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

how to Binding DataTrigger with my filed 'place' of DataTable?

Comment: Please show some code of your model behind this presentation.

Comment: <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Place}"
'Place is name of field in DataTable that set for ItemSource of DataGrid in C# code

In fact I not have Model. I jast have DataTable.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. I think you need to add some code to get some correct help here.

Comment: I edit my question and add C# code. please see it.

Comment: So `Binding Place` should do the trick. Also note a string as value is case sensitive.

Comment: That is it should work correct?

Comment: It is worked :)
but I have new question. How to do set background in C# code?
and 
How to set background for just a cell not for a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this question is in this note:

**string as value is case sensitive**

The string in field place must be equal with string in value of  tag.